# C#. Записать текст из RichTextBox в одну строку в файле и потом считать из файла снова в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, строки, файлы, replace, richtextbox

Нужно из RichTextBox записать многострочный текст в одну строку в файл txt, таким образом, чтобы потом можно было из этой строки в файле его обратно считать в RichTextBox и он выводился как многострочный. Это преодолимо?

Comment: А откуда взялось такое странное условие? И что делать с форматированием?

Comment: А так — всё можно, ну ввести какой-нибудь escape-символ.

Comment: есть данность, что такое условие есть, а с форматирование сохранить

Comment: а что за escape символ? - я новичек

Comment: А, ну если есть данность, то можно, но работы много, и вручную.

Comment: Ну, как в строках на C# обозначается перевод строки? Подумайте, как применить ту же идею.

Comment: то есть придумать свое сочетание символов, которое использоватать как спец. слова?

Comment: WinForms или WPF? Добавьте тег. У `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` есть свойство [Rtf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx). Вот его и писать в файл. Из файла читать в него же.